# AngularJS directive not displaying the template

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Here is my AngularJs directive. Its' expected to show the div in the template but it shown nothing while the code is run.

Here is the html

```
<div ng-app="SuperHero">
    <SuperMan></SuperMan>
</div>
```

Here is the AngularJS directive

```
var app = angular.module('SuperHero',[]);
app.directive('SuperMan',function(){
    return{
        restrict:'E',
        template: '<div>Hello fromt Directive</div>'
    }
});
```

And here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QUP97/)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

When you declare your directive you used the name `SuperMan`, however this is wrong. You should use `superMan` as that will be translated to `super-man` as the element.

Any capital letter in the directive name will translate to a hyphen, as capital letters are not used in elements. For example `myDirective` will translate to `my-directive`.

As mentioned by others, AngularJS uses normalisation the following normalisation rules:

> Strip x- and data- from the front of the element/attributes. Convert
>   the :, -, or _-delimited name to camelCase.

JavaScript:

```
var app = angular.module('SuperHero',[]);
app.directive('superMan',function(){
    return{
        restrict:'E',
        template: '<div>Hello fromt Directive</div>'
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="SuperHero">
    <super-man></super-man>
</div>
```

I updated your fiddle to match the correct syntax here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QUP97/1/).

Answer (score 1):

Angular [normalizes directives names](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) - using camelCase in the directive and dash seperated (usually) since html isn't case sensitive, in the template.

so where you need to call the directive named`superMan`
with:

```
<super-man></super-man>
```

Here is a **working [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/at7Tw/)**

Answer (score 0):

> Angular normalizes an element's tag and attribute name to determine
>   which elements match which directives. We typically refer to
>   directives by their case-sensitive camelCase normalized name (e.g.
>   ngModel). However, since HTML is case-insensitive, we refer to
>   directives in the DOM by lower-case forms, typically using
>   dash-delimited attributes on DOM elements (e.g. ng-model).
>
> The normalization process is as follows:
>
> **Strip x- and data- from the front of the element/attributes. Convert
>   the :, -, or _-delimited name to camelCase.**
>
> https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

You should have a camelCase name for your directive: eg `superMan`, and use one of the following syntax to call your directive, as **HTML is case-insensitive**:

```
<super-man></super-man>
<super_man></super_man>
<super:man></super:man>
<SuPer_man></sUpEr_mAn> //HTML is case Insensitive
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QUP97/3/