# angular typescript component not displaying the template

Tags: angularjs, typescript

Following this question and resolution:
[AngularJS directive not displaying the template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24078366/angularjs-directive-not-displaying-the-template)

I wanted to try the same with an angular component and typescript, but i can't seem to get it working.  The component just doesn't show.

My html looks like this:

```
<div ng-app="SuperHero">
    <super-man></super-man>
</div>
```

My Typescript looks like this:

```
module Application.Components {
    export class superMan implements ng.IComponentOptions {
        template: string = "<h1>Hello from component</h1>";
    }
}

var appModule = angular.module("SuperHero", []);
appModule.component("superMan", () => Application.Components.superMan);
```

A fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/589301uo/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Component definition takes configuration object, not a function. So in your example you should use `new Application.Components.superMan()` instead of `() => Application.Components.superMan`.

Also pay attention that components were added in angular 1.5 and your fiddle uses older version.

[Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/d4xmb368/) working demo.